# Unable to import OpenEXR

Tags: python, computer-vision, deep-learning, openexr

I am unable to import OpenEXR module in jupyter notebook. On importing it throws the following error.
I am using MacOS High Sierra. And working inside a conda environment.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/siddharthdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenEXR-1.3.0-py3.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/OpenEXR.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN7Imf_2_214TypedAttributeISsE13readValueFromERNS_7IStreamEii
    Referenced from: /Users/siddharthdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenEXR-1.3.0-py3.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/OpenEXR.cpython-36m-darwin.so
    Expected in: flat namespace in /Users/siddharthdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenEXR-1.3.0-py3.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/OpenEXR.cpython-36m-darwin.so'
```

Tell me how to resolve this.